# Conservation of Power in Filters

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, rf, filter, signal

I have a simple doubt about the conservation of power in systems that include some filters.

Let's consider this general situation:

[image]

The filter is able to attenuate some components (of certain frequencies) of Vin. This means that the power of Vout is lower than that of Vin. I have the following questions:

1) Where does the power Pout - Pin go? If I look for instance at the following example, I'd say that it is dissipated on R, since for all frequencies such that Vout = 0, all Vin drops on R.

[image]

Is it correct?

2) Is the previous reasoning true for any type of filters? If it is true, it means that it is not possible to realize filters without resistors (not even ideally): otherwise, where will the power Pout - Pin go?

3) I have noticed that filters that are used in microwave/rf circuits are considered as "reflection attenuators": they (ideally) do not have losses, since power Pout - Pin is reflected by them. But, exactly what does it mean? Which component stores or dissipate that power?

Comment: *", it means that it is not possible to realize filters without resistors"* Gosh, I will have to throw all all my speaker cross over filters which are only L and C.

Comment: L-C filters can be realised without resistors (though many operate into a terminating resistor such as 50R). These are essentially lossless (disregarding non-ideal components). They operate - like your "reflection attenuators" by not accepting power from the source in the first place (parallel LC circuit has infinite impedance at resonance)

Comment: I think you're conflating resistance with the general concept of impedance. Only the real part of the (generally complex) impedance of a component contributes to power loss. I think your statement "it is not possible to realize filters without resistors" should really be "it is not possible to realize filters without *impedance*". Ideal resistors have only real impedance (i.e. *resistance*), and ideal capacitors and inductors have only imaginary impedance (also called *reactance*). In reality, all components have both types of impedance.

Comment: Note that in all circumstances the signal path from input to output goes through resistor R, and therefore part of its energy is transferred to heat there. This is the case whether the power is transferred to the output (at low frequencies) or to ground via the capacitor (at high frequencies).

Comment: The phenomena of resistance is always there and there is always Joule loss in any given circuit excluding supra conductive circuit.

Comment: The primary factor that contribute to attenuate frequency in a circuit is the dynamic response of the filter of itself. An inductance will attenuate higher frequency when inline with an AC source. However, no power is dissipate if you consider an ideal component. Attenuation doesn't necessarily mean loss which is related to the Joule dissipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering *power* a filter block must have a load resistor (that's where power is delivered). Delivering power to a filter block's input side also involves a source resistor.
The filter block itself may include resistors, and/or lossy reactive components. The simplest case to consider is where the filter block only includes reactive (L, C) components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLtmbR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 The filter block of reactive components **cannot dissipate real power** but it can temporarily store or transfer power amongst its neighbouring reactive components. Power is either delivered to **Rload** or it is refused by its input. Any real power accepted at the filter block's input side must be (eventually) delivered to **Rload**.

Referring to a filter block as a *reflection attenuator* reinforces this point of view. Power refused at the filter's input side can be considered a reflection of power back to the signal source where it would be dissipated by **Rsource**.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) I have noticed that filters that are used in microwave/rf circuits are considered as "reflection attenuators": they (ideally) do not have losses, since power Pout - Pin is reflected by them. But, exactly what does it mean? Which component stores or dissipate that power?

The filter reflects back the power it doesn't transmit to the load. The component that dissipates the power is the output impedance of the source.

In the completely ideal, artificial, case of a source with zero output impedance, and no dissipation on the load side (so either short or open circuit), and a lossless LC filter circuit between them, the filter reponse could grow indefinitely, becoming infinite after an infinite time. However, that doesn't happen in the real world, there's always some dissipation somewhere.